# android AccountManager.getAccountsByType

Tags: android

I got a crash

> android.os.TransactionTooLargeException android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByTypeAsUser(AccountManager.java:450) android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountManager.java:441) "

when I using `getAccountsByType("com.google")` to get `Accouts`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Include in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Use the below method to get your account:

```
public void getAccount() {
        AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();

        for (Account account : list) {
            if (account.type.equals("com.google")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "account = " + account.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had included  the permission in Manifest. what's the difference between your method and mine? Is getAccounts() better than getAccountsByType()?

Comment: getAccounts() will return all accounts have signed in in your phone, if you want to get specific account like Google, use a loop to filter your result. I'm not sure why getAccountsByType() throw error, so try my method to get accounts is a solution to your problem.

Comment: as we know, TransactionTooLargeException will be thrown when Binder transaction is too large. it means that the return value of getAccountsByType is too large.if i use the getAccounts, it will return more Accounts.

Comment: shouldn't  AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE); be AccountManager manager=AccountManager.get(context); that is what I have seen but I suppose both work